# Column Control Tab issue in CQ5

Tags: aem

I have created a CQ form, under this form is my column control (2 column).
Inside column control I have form elements like select1 -> select2 -> title1 -> title 2

Now when I run this page in preview or publish instance, and press tab key within the element, it goes as Select1 -> title1 -> select2 -> title2.

I want to control the tab press here so as it goes as select1 - select2 - title1 -title2

Any views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use tabindex attribute on each form element, like so:

```
col1:
<input type="text" name="title1" tabindex="1">
<select name="select1" tabindex="2">...</select>

col2:
<input type="text" name="title2" tabindex="3">
<select name="select2" tabindex="4">...</select>
```